# Attempting to move file in UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo callback fails with "you don't have permission" error

Tags: ios, ios13.7

Here is my code for displaying an image picker:

```
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.allowsEditing = false
        pickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
```

In the delegate I have:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL
        else { return }
    do {
        let newFileLocation = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString + ".mov")
        FileManager.default.moveItem(at: videoURL, to: newFileLocation)
    } catch {
        // “trim.92501481-FA5B-490C-8F55-575DE076C8A1.MOV” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “tmp”
    }
}
```

I went back and tried this on iOS 13.5 and it works fine, but in iOS 13.7 I am getting this strange error.

Comment: @matt Ok i edited it but that isn't the source of the problem, I just ad-libbed that part for SO

Answer (score 1):

Ah simple fix, change:

```
FileManager.default.moveItem(at: videoURL, to: newFileLocation)
```

to

```
FileManager.default.copyItem(at: videoURL, to: newFileLocation)
```

Comment: Excellent! The reason I didn’t suggest that earlier is that I assumed you didn’t want to copy, because it is so time consuming. But I guess you’ll just have to live with that.

Comment: I'm more concerned with making sure the video uploads reliably - using url session's background upload api for that. So yea, working great so far

Comment: I'd like to point out that iOS 13.7 has APFS, which should make copy just as fast as move, since it doesn't REALLY copy. Also, in iOS 14.8.1, moveItem works for me (although it obviously cannot be relied on to always work).

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the same problem and solution.  The funny thing is that if you're doing this for the camera, moving the file works.  But if you're doing this for the Camera Roll, it doesn't.  Worse of course is that Apple changed this behavior without documenting it anywhere.  I too have been using "move" for years for obvious efficiency reasons.

Also, the error says that the app doesn't have permission for the destination folder, when in fact the permission is lacking for the source folder.  So no help from iOS here.